# userinfo in HTML href

Tags: html, href, google-chrome-devtools, userinfo

I have noticed that when I use the userinfo part (user:password) in an HTML attribute such as `href` or `src`, the Chrome dev tools seem to go crazy.

For example, if I navigate to `http://localhost:8080` and the displayed document's HTML contains this:

```
<a href="http://kaczka:dziwaczka@google.pl">yo mama</a>
```

then the dev tools, upon hovering or copying the attribute value, yield `http://localhost:8080/http://kaczka:dziwaczka@google.pl`.

The link itself, however, works correctly when simply clicked.

Does anybody know wheter this is an issue with Chrome dev tools or some intentional feature? If this is intentional, why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not by design. Rather, this type of URL has never been regarded to be completed correctly. Generally speaking, this type of credentials specification has been deprecated - use the `Authorization` HTTP header instead (see [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters) and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123150).